# Laravel 5 geting 500 error in hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I spend my evening to run my laravel application in hosting.

In localhost on mac os everything is ok, but in the hosting on ubuntu I get 500 error.

I have not any clue.

.htaccess in root

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(\.json|\.lock|\.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

and .htaccess in public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If I delete /public/.htaccess I get `server error 500`

else I get `Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://oboi.spb.ru/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.`

Comment: Are you unable to set the DocumentRoot for Apache to the `public` directory on the server?

Comment: Do you get laravel's 500 error? Can you enable debugging and show the error?

Comment: look at folder permission (storage, logs)
`storage` folder should have app, framework, logs and bootstrap/cache

Comment: @Bogdan, i cannot sat DocumentRoot in tis hosting, another site are working fine

Comment: @EduardoPacios, i get laravel's 500 error. The storege/logs/laravel.log does not chance

Comment: @JuanE., I set permission 777 for folder storage and logs.

Comment: @Yurich you need to set premission 777 at bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 1):

The Condition :

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
```

fails because because you are missing a **/** before the **public** in your Cond pattern so the Rule is being applied on every request causing an infinite recursion.

Change the Cond pattern to

```
!^/public
```